# Understand the connection strings in Coveo

Tags: coveo

I am very new to Coveo. We are trying to introduce a new environment in between QA and Prod.I have just duplicate the QA Setup for this. What are the settings and connection strings that i have to change so that the whole environment doesn't reference QA anymore

Comment: what is your Sitecore and Coveo version? and please clear your requirement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For Coveo Cloud Platform for Hive***:

**Local Search information:**

Log into the Coveo Cloud Manager from your sitecore instance's Control panel. From there you will log in from the configuration tab. This will update a few items that you can add into source control, which exist in the *App_Config/Include/Coveo/Coveo.SearchProvider.Custom.config* file. These will be the farmname, username, and password for the default index configuration.

**Cloud Connection Information:**

You can also update the information per environment in the *App_Config/Include/Cove/Cove.CloudPlatfromClient.Custom.config* file. You would update the apiKey, organizationId, and searchApiKey in this location for each environment. Keep in mind that this is what points to the Coveo organization, so if you have different organizations for environments, this is where you would change the info. If you need a new apiKey, log into platform.cloud.coveo.com, select the organization and then generate a new APIKEY if needed. An apikey is usually generated upon each install in an environment but sometimes it is necessary to get a new one.

Comment: Big Thanks for the response , We still use legacy JS framework ,On premise ,Sietcore 8.1 and Coveo 4.0 are they same in my case as well ?Please advise

Comment: Unfortunately I am not as familiar with On Prem as the cloud option.